# Creating unique keys for my dictionary of arrays

Tags: ios

Could someone tell me how to create the current date and time as a unique key for my dictionary. I am using the code below but the keys are not unique when entered a few seconds apart.

```
NSDateFormatter *currDate =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[currDate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

[self.transDict setObject:self.transArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
    [currDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]];
```

As you can tell I am a novice...appreciate any help
thx

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should find out if your formatter is working.

Change the last line to look something like this:

```
NSString * currentDateAsString = [currDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
if(currentDateAsString)
{
    [self.transDict setObject: self.transArray forKey: currentDateAsString];
} else {
    NSLog( @"why did my date formatter fail?" );
}
```

You don't need to do the `[NSString stringWithFormat:...` bit as `stringFromDate` is already returning a `NSString` object, which is all you need for a key.

Lastly, if you're not using ARC, don't forget to release the date formatter you created (via alloc & init).

Comment: Thank-you for your comments. I put in some NSLog output that indicates my keys are changing but the count of the dict remains constant. Looks like I have more research to do. The date does not seem like a good string to use as a key.